# Getting list of QgsPoint from polygon Layer in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, point-in-polygon

How do I manage the points in a layer?

```
from qgis.core import *

def run_script(iface):
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(layerType.Polygon+'?'+crs.psg_4326,
                       'la-florida', 
                       vectorLayerType.memory)
```

In this moment I need to get all vertex from the polygon which represent the region bound, but I have not find the documentation about how to get it.

Comment: What issues are you having with the code that you have in your question?

Comment: Is not a issue, is a question about how to get the points from the polygon. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need objects for **QgsGeometry** class. In my example (polygon layer with only one feature):

[image]

the next code gets the list points of the polygon layer:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feature = layer.getFeatures().next()

polygon = feature.geometry().asPolygon()

n = len(polygon[0])

for i in range(n):
    print polygon[0][i]
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I got each polygon point as a tuple:

```
(384465,4.45043e+06)
(392424,4.46131e+06)
(409514,4.45616e+06)
(411269,4.44282e+06)
(404480,4.43076e+06)
(392541,4.43486e+06)
(381773,4.44118e+06)
(384465,4.45043e+06)
```

Observe that the first and last points are matched.

**Editing Note:**

I edited my answer based in your comment. Next code uses **QgsVectorLayer** class constructor.

```
import os
my_path = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp'  #this is a Linux path
root,name = os.path.split(my_path)
name = name[:-4]

layer = QgsVectorLayer(my_path,
                       name, 
                       'ogr')  #This is my provider: in your code is memory

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

feature = layer.getFeatures().next()

polygon = feature.geometry().asPolygon()

n = len(polygon[0])

for i in range(n):
    print polygon[0][i]
```

Comment: thanks, ¿but if I want to make a standalone application? in this case I haven't a iface object. thanks.

Comment: You use the layer reference got with the class constructor: `layer = QgsVectorLayer(layerType.Polygon+'?'+crs.psg_4326, ...` after adding the layer to the registry (`QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)`). In the next link (in spanish) you have a complete standalone application: https://joseguerreroa.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/visor-de-shapefiles-con-qgis-python-y-qt-en-gnudebian/

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand how to get the geometry from the object called "layer" in my code. thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example.