# Understanding nested list of asPolygon in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

In [Getting list of QgsPoint from polygon Layer in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173149), a user explains how to get the coordinates of a polygon and gives the following code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
feature = layer.getFeatures().next()
polygon = feature.geometry().asPolygon()
n = len(polygon[0])
for i in range(n):
     print polygon[0][i]
```

What is polygon[0] in this case and what would be polygon [5] for example?

In the `for i in range(n)` part it seems that `i` represents the vertex number of the polygon and its coordinates. But I don't get the first polygon[0].

Comment: Even singleton polygons can have multiple rings. The documentation should describe the output of that function, to confirm that the first radix is ring number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method asPolygon grabs an object. It’s a QgisPolygonXY http://qgis.org/api/qgsgeometry_8h.html#a271a798c4388adbfcfda3f8b3ec289df
As you can see in description:
Polygon: first item of the list is outer ring, inner rings (if any) start from second item.

So the first item you extract using polygon[0] is an outer ring. Then you iterate over this ring.